# brew error SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO

Tags: macos, ssl, curl, openssl, homebrew

I'm trying to install cairo on mac 10.13.6 using brew 1.2.2. I'm getting this error:

```
curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

I'm behind a corporate proxy and have set the http_proxy and https_proxy variables. When I use the brew verbose option it looks like it is using Apple's default curl libraries (not sure why, but various comments hint that this version is problematic):

```
brew install -v cairo
...
Downloading https://...libpng...
/usr/bin/curl --remote-time --location --user-agent ...
curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

Check version:

```
/usr/bin/curl --version
curl 7.54.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin17.0) libcurl/7.54.0 LibreSSL/2.0.20 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.24.0
```

I downloaded and built the newest curl library from [here](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html). Using this curl install I can download libpng manually.

```
./configure --prefix=~/curl --with-darwinssl
curl ...libpng... > libpng-1.6.34.tar.xz
```

I tried to get brew to use this curl install by prefixing my path:

```
export PATH=~/curl:$PATH
```

But it looks like brew is still using Apple's curl lib (output did not change from the above).

**My question is: how do I make brew use this new curl install? Or am I just on the wrong track to make this work?**

Comment: *"...have set the http_proxy and https_proxy variables..."* - while you don't provide details at what values you've set these variables an error often made is to set `https_proxy` to some `https://proxy:port` instead of `http://proxy:port`. Other then that it might be that the proxy is blocking the connection by policy.

Comment: Wow, that seems to have been it. Didn't realize that could be an issue. Is this an issue with curl or just commonly how proxy servers are configured?

Comment: That's more an issue that users don't understand how proxying HTTPS works and assume that to proxy HTTPS one need to access a proxy by HTTPS too.  But instead a [CONNECT request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/CONNECT) is sent over a plain connection to a proxy to build a tunnel to the final target and then end-to-end HTTPS is spoken using this tunnel.